# Grafana Elasticsearch convert table into graph

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have two columns table in Grafana created from Elasticsearch datasource.

Example, response time:

- time : count
- 0-100 : 23
- 100-200 : 344
- 200-300 : 234
- ....

I'd like to convert/transform this table into a graph, to be able to see on X-axis constant values like 0-100, 100-200, etc., and on Y-axis changeable values like 23, 344, etc.

Is it possible in some way?

Comment: Which Grafana version is being used?

Comment: @rohatgisanat 7.2.0